Mel keeps throwing an error when I try to print the value of a variable
I have a simple scene consisting of curve1 and curve2, I have both of them selected.
I want to query my selection and save it $selection and then print $selection, just to confirm if it worked:
string $selection[] = `ls -selection`;
$selection[0];
$selection[1];

But the script editor errors out with:
// Error: $selection[0];
// Error: Line 2.14: Syntax error
// Error: $selection[1];
// Error: Line 3.14: Syntax error

I tried swapping things around or removing the trailing ; just for the variable lines:
string $selection[] = `ls -selection`;
$selection[0]
$selection[1]

I just end up getting a similar error
When I run all three lines I am expecting to get some kind of confirmation of what is contained in $selection.
For example by just running ls -selection;, I get an output of:
// Result: curve1 curve2

Does $selection actually have a value at all? or am I just not printing it right?
PS: I know this is probably easier with Python but I am specifically learning Mel.
Thanks for any help.

Printing in mel works differently: print($selection[0]);.

@haggikrey hey that did it, thank you so much. Should propose it as an answer.
